# Why isn't my script filling in the template.txt? [Django 1.9.5]

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am writing an email script. The user will fill in the form on my site and then after hitting 'submit' the form sends me an email and lists the form fields.

I was following this tutorial which uses an older version of Django (I think 1.7.5) [Django Email Tutorial](http://hellowebapp.com/news/tutorial-setting-up-a-contact-form-with-django/)

Here is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from website.forms import ContactForm
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.template import Context


# these function generate your webpages

def render1(request):
    return render(request, 'website/home.html')

def contact(request):
    form_class = ContactForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            contact_name = request.POST.get(
                'contact_name'
            , '')
            contact_email = request.POST.get(
                'contact_email'
            , '')
            form_content = request.POST.get('content', '')

            template = get_template('contact_template.txt')
            context = Context({
                'contact_name': contact_name,
                'contact_email': contact_email,
                'form_content': form_content,
            })
            content = template.render({'contact_name': contact_name,         'contact_email': contact_email, 'form_content': form_content})

            email = EmailMessage("New contact form submission", content, "Your website" +'', ['zach@thewhsellc.com'], headers = {'Reply-        To': contact_email } )
            email.send()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('contact')

    return render(request, 'website/contact.html', { 'form': form_class, })
```

I don't get any errors in my terminal when ran.

[Terminal Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsqyZ.png)

Comment: You should post that template. Are you receiving an email at all?

Comment: Please check the value returned from `email.send()` - is an email being tried and not being sent? It can happen that the email is being sent but rejected by the email receiver. Also check if the template is being properly read and the content is not empty.